# Intuitive interpretation of (sub modularity) $F(A) + F(B) \geq F(A \cup B) + F(A \cap B)$

Tags: functions

I was trying to understand the intuitive interpretation of the equation:

$$F(A) + F(B) \geq F(A \cup B) + F(A \cap B)$$

Where F is a function that is sub modular (i.e. satisfies the above inequality).

I know that it is equivalent to sub modularity and hence, has a different formulation of diminishing marginal returns. However, that interpretation is not obvious just from the equation above (however it is obvious with its alternative formulation).

Hence I was wondering, if anyone had a intuitive interpretation on its form: $F(A) + F(B) \geq F(A \cup B) + F(A \cap B)$.

Comment: Offhand, the first question that comes to mind is: what is $F$? Seems like that's probably an important thing to mention.

Comment: @CameronBuie F is a function that satisfies the inequality I wrote. Let me make my question a little more clear. I apologize.